# Convert Un-Formatted Text to Date Without Using Default Current Date

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, format

I am attempting to extract dates from a data frame column containing raw text that isn't in a particular format, without incorporating data from the current date that the script is run in.

Below are some examples of the text formats:

```
"dec", "12", "12/31", "1995", "december", "31/95", "12/95"
```

I am currently using a function with the following conversion operation (with `text` as the input):

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(parser.parse(text).timestamp()).month    
datetime.fromtimestamp(parser.parse(text).timestamp()).day
datetime.fromtimestamp(parser.parse(text).timestamp()).year
```

However, this incorporates data from the current date if that information is not provided in the text. For example, if today is April 14th, 2021:

```
"dec": 12 14 2021, "12": 12 14 2021, "12/31": 12 31 2021, "1995": 4 14 1995, "december": 12 14 21,"31/95": nan nan nan, "12/95": 12 14 1995
```

Is there a way to perform a similar operation, but without incorporating data from the current date? Ideally, something similar to:

```
"dec": 12 nan nan, "12": 12 nan nan, "12/31": 12 31 nan, "1995": nan nan 1995, "december": 12 nan nan,"31/95": nan 31 1995, "12/95": 12 12 1995
```

Comment: Afaik there's no way to tell for dateutil's parser which fields were actually parsed and which were taken from the default. You could see if you can modify the [src](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil) to do so.

Comment: That's my answer, then-- thanks!